# view.GONE is not working progressbar in RecyclerView.OnBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

the progressbar in onbindviewholder method is not working

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem item = listdata.get(position);
    final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    final TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);

    //view.GONE is not working in this method but TextView 

    final ProgressBar progressBar;
    progressBar=(ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
 }
```

Comment: You're inflating a new, unused layout there. The `ProgressBar` you're calling `setVisibility()` on is not one you see on-screen. Get rid of the inflation and `findViewById()` calls, and call `setVisibility()` in the `ProgressBar` in `holder`, like you are the `TextView` there, assuming you've set up the `ProgressBar` in `holder` correctly.

Comment: @mike can you show me example i am kind of lost lost

Comment: There's not much to show. It's mostly just removing stuff from that you've got. Assuming you've set up the `ProgressBar` in `DataHolder` the same way you did the `title` `TextView` there, you just need to call `setVisibility()` on that; e.g., `holder.progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);`. You can then remove all of the lines from `final View view = ...` to `progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);` that you currently have in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inflating `View` and packing it up inside `ViewHolder` (in your case `DataHolder`) have place in `onCreateViewHolder` method.

inside `onBindViewHolder` you are only refering to previously created `View`. Do not inflate new one, use previously created (this is recycling) and set it like your `item` object says

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem item = listdata.get(position);
    ...
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(item.shouldBeVisible() ? Visibility.VISIBLE : Visibility.GONE);
}
```